# redirect relative path Express.js goes wrong

Tags: javascript, express

redirect method not work as expect. it can't get the page with relative path. if absolute its fine. like https://www.google.com. but when i put relative path index.html same as post.html directory. it can't fetched it. from code if input form value is admin it will redirect page to index.html

Node script

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/post.html'));

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    if(username == 'admin'){
    res.redirect(__dirname + '/index.html');
    }
    res.end();
});

http.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Listening on *:80');
    });
```

html script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
<input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing __dirname. It returns the current script folder path.

Comment: @TheodorB still returns **Cannot get /index.html**

Comment: try `return res.redirect(__dirname + '/index.html');`

Comment: Also, try return res.redirect instead of res.end();

Comment: @TheodorB __dirnamme is OK as he need to specify the file path

Comment: @GeorgeBailey same result with or without return. it returns **This site can’t be reached**

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to expose the `index.html` file to the clients, right now, they can only access `post.html`.

To do this, you can either add a new route for the index page, or use `express.static()` to serve the files.

If you want to go with the first solution, add a route like this:

```
app.get('/index', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

and then redirect to it in the next block:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    if(username == 'admin'){
      res.redirect('/index');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

If you want to use `express.static()`, this is how you'd do that:

Put the files you want the clients to access in another directory (this is mostly called "public") in your app's root dir (where the Node Script is located). After that use the `express.static()` function to tell Express to serve the directory like an Apache Server would:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'))
```

After that you can redirect the clients to `/index.html`

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    if(username == 'admin'){
      res.redirect('/index.html');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: The first one is work. but the second not work. it always display index.html.

Comment: and the first one is is like load 2 page directly but hide the one until request. it will make load slow.

Comment: How does it load two pages simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand how `redirect` works. Just look at the documentation [expressjs.com#res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect).
There you can find that you can use `redirect` method only for moving from one path to another.

Anyway, you used it incorrectly.

This code wouldn't work: `res.redirect(__dirname + '/index.html');`

Comment: If so. what method that same as header(Location: index.html) in php?

Comment: the method is the correct one, just not how you used it

Comment: @Luca the method is incorrect. You can't use `__dirname` as a path in redirect method without creating the same path block which could handle it.

Comment: res.redirect() is the correct function to use when trying to redirect the client to another resource. ___The way the OP used res.redirect() is not correct___

Comment: I meant the same. I wrote `you can use redirect method only for moving from one path to another`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  __dirname + '/index.html'
```

That will be something like:

```
 "C:/some/crazy/path/index.html"
```

Now this will be sent to the client. And that can't just access your local file system over the wire for good reasons. So instead of redirecting to a certain file (won't work), just redirect to an url that is hosted by your server (hint: `index.html` is no route):

```
 res.redirect("/");
```